# Printer GPO Error Code '0x80070bcb'

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, print-server, shared-printers

When trying to deploy label printers via GPO, I am receiving the error of

> Group Policy Object did not apply because it failed with error code '0x80070bcb The specified printer driver was not found on the system and needs to be downloaded.'

in event viewer.

There are a few different label printers I am trying to deploy, some Zebra, some Printronix, and some Datamax printers

I have tried everything I could think of when deploying the printers, this includes

- the methods of installation for the printers via GPO or GPP
- Changing the Point and Print Restrictions
- Trying to install the printers as either a user or a computer configuration
- Installation of different printers

All of the printers are located on a print server with the print services enabled.  I have tried to deploy regular office printers and that works fine.  The only issue I am having is with label printers not deploying to either the user or computer.

When I look at the GPresult I find that the label printer GPO was applied, yet nothing shows up or is working in regards to that printer

Comment: There is more to it, So the only drivers I am having issue with are drivers provided by Seagull.  The bad part about that is that the Datamax print drivers go through Seagull.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone else.  Microsoft has an [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5005652-manage-new-point-and-print-default-driver-installation-behavior-cve-2021-34481-873642bf-2634-49c5-a23b-6d8e9a302872) which gave me part of what I was looking for.
Modifying not only the key mentioned in the article, but two others resolved the issue and I am able to deploy the printers from the print server through GPO.
The three I modified were:

- RestrictDriverInstallationToAdministrators
- Restricted
- UpdatePromptSettings

These were modified in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Printers\PointAndPrint` Registry location